# paperclip callbacks or simple processor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, amazon-s3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3

I wanted to run the callback `after_post_process` but it doesn't seem to work in Rails 3.0.1 using Paperclip 2.3.8.  It gives an error:

```
undefined method `_post_process_callbacks' for #<Class:0x102d55ea0>
```

I want to call the Panda API after the file has been uploaded.  I would have created my own processor for this, but as Panda handles the processing, and it can upload the files as well, and queue itself for an undetermined duration I thought a callback would do fine.  But the callbacks don't seem to work in Rails3.

```
after_post_process :panda_create

    def panda_create
      video = Panda::Video.create(:source_url => mp3.url.gsub(/[?]\d*/,''), :profiles => "f4475446032025d7216226ad8987f8e9", :path_format => "blah/1234")
    end
```

I tried require and include for paperclip in my model but it didn't seem to matter.

Anyideas?

Comment: In which line in paperclip does the error occur?

Answer (score 47):

Solution...

I put the callback after the paperclip has_attached in the given model and it works beautifully.  I was just so used to always putting the callback at the top of all models that this didn't occur to me til later.

Answer (score 9):

Moving the has_attached_file attribute **above** the validates_presence_of and validates_attachment
in your model still needs to be done it seems. I just ran into the same problem in my Rails 4/Ruby 2 implementation of PaperClip and putting it above fixed it.

Comment: I had the same problem when updating the Paperclip gem.  Your fix worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem because the name of my paperclip image property did not match the name I was validating against.

`as_attached_file :image
validates_attachment_content_type: :not_image`