# How do I get the storage of each user account to update when a new file is uploaded - in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What I would like to happen is every single time a new file is uploaded, `user.space_used` is updated.

But that doesn't happen right now. In order to get an update, I have to manually run `user.update_space` at the console to update a specific user, or use an array to cycle through all the users and update it like that.

How do I get it to do it at the right time - also, it would be nice if I could verify that the `space_used` column on the `User` model has the total sum of the filesizes of all the files uploaded for that user on the `Upload` model.

My user model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110412170916
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                   :integer         not null, primary key
#  email                :string(255)
#  encrypted_password   :string(128)
#  password_salt        :string(255)
#  reset_password_token :string(255)
#  remember_token       :string(255)
#  remember_created_at  :datetime
#  sign_in_count        :integer
#  current_sign_in_at   :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at      :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip   :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip      :string(255)
#  username             :string(255)
#  first_name           :string(255)
#  last_name            :string(255)
#  created_at           :datetime
#  updated_at           :datetime
#  invitation_token     :string(60)
#  invitation_sent_at   :datetime
#  plan_id              :integer
#  current_state        :string(255)
#  confirmation_token   :string(255)
#  confirmed_at         :datetime
#  confirmation_sent_at :datetime
#  space_used           :integer         default(0), not null
#  failed_attempts      :integer         default(0)
#  unlock_token         :string(255)
#  locked_at            :datetime
#  trial_end_date       :date
#  active_subscription  :boolean
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_voter
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invitable, :lockable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :first_name, :last_name, :plan_id

    after_save  :update_space

  def role_symbols
    roles.map do |role|
      role.name.underscore.to_sym
    end
  end

  def update_space
       total_size = 0
         if self.uploads.count > 0
           self.uploads.each do |upload|
             total_size += upload[:image_file_size]
           end
         end
    self.space_used = total_size

  end

    def space_threshold_reached?
        self.plan.storage == self.space_used        
    end

    def space_left
        (self.plan.storage * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) - self.space_used.to_f     
    end


end
```

My Upload model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110330215959
#
# Table name: uploads
#
#  id                 :integer         not null, primary key
#  name               :string(255)
#  description        :string(255)
#  image_file_name    :string(255)
#  image_content_type :string(255)
#  image_file_size    :integer
#  image_updated_at   :datetime
#  stage_id           :integer
#  user_id            :integer
#  created_at         :datetime
#  updated_at         :datetime

class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_voteable
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { 
                                                                :thumb => "64x64" },
                                                            :storage => :s3,
                                                            :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"

    validates_attachment_presence :image                    
  validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 10.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/JPG']

    after_post_process :update_users_space_used

    def self.total_used
        total_size = 0
        all.each do |upload|
            total_size += upload.image_file_size
        end
        return total_size
    end

    def update_users_space_used
        Authorization.current_user.space_used += self.image_file_size       
    end


end
```

Thanks.

Edit1: Btw, I am using paperclip to manage the uploads.

Edit2: In the `Upload.rb` model, I changed the `before_save` to the `after_post_process` callback for paperclip and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Paperclip's `after_post_process` callback would be what you want.

Comment: Have an example of what that would look like ? I see references to it in the github readme, but no example of an implementation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528287/paperclip-callbacks-or-simple-processor has an example.

Comment: Nope...that didn't work. I have updated the code in the question to show what I have done.

Comment: I think you'd need to call Authorization.current_user.increment(:space_used, self.image_file_size). Otherwise it won't be persisted.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the actual code you are proposing ? Not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @marcamillion: You may have to use increment! instead so that it actually saves the user.